# DynamoDB remove Map from List where property equals value

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

How can I remove a map inside of a list in dynamo using a property value?

This is the dynamo record structure

```
{
  "authorizedUsers": [
    {
      "name": "Bob",
      "phoneNumber": "822-222-2221"
    },
    {
      "name": "Joe",
      "phoneNumber": "111-111-2221"
    }
  ],
  "PK": "users"
}
```

currently I have

```
    var params = {
        TableName: 'userTable',
        Key: {
            PK: 'users'
        },
        UpdateExpression: 'REMOVE authorizedUsers[0]',
        ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW'
    };

    try {
        await docClient.update(params).promise();
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error(e.message);
    }
```

and this removes the first record no problem, but I need the expression to be more dynamic and be able to remove the row by phoneNumber (unique identifier)
How can I modify this to use the phoneNumber to identify the correct Map inside List to remove?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the `phoneNumber` to identify a map item inside the list.

You state that `phoneNumber` is a unique identifier. I suggest to change the model of your item to not use arrays, and instead use a map with the `phoneNumber` as the key.

```json
{
  "authorizedUsers": {
    "822-222-2221": {
      "name": "Bob",
      "phoneNumber": "822-222-2221"
    },
    "111-111-2221": {
      "name": "Joe",
      "phoneNumber": "111-111-2221"
    }
  ,
  "PK": "users"
}
```

If you cannot change the structure of the item, consider versioning the item and over-writing the whole `authorizedUsers` array attribute. You will want to create a Version_ID on all items as a one off operation (or don't and assume an implicit version of `0` for all items without a version number).

When you want to update an `authorizedUsers` attribute on an item, first read the item. Then create an `Update` operation with the new array, and also increment the Version_ID attribute. Finally, add a `ConditionExpression` to check the `Version_ID` attribute value is still the value when you first read the item, to make sure another process hasn't updated the item in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I did that and it made it much easier to write dynamo expression to add and remove users from dynamo record.